# file_exists returns false between file_put_content (or fwrite) and unlink in second execution

Tags: php

I'm working on a cron system and need to execute a script only once at a time. By using the following codes, I execute the script first time and while it's looping (for delaying purpose), executing it again but file_exists always returns false while first execution returns content of file after loop is done.

Cronjob.php:

```
include "Locker.class.php";

Locker::$LockName = __DIR__.'/OneTime_[cron].lock';
$Locker = new Locker();

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    echo 'Z';
    $z = true;
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_start();
}
```

Locker.class.php:

```
class Locker{
    static $LockName;
    function __construct($Expire){

        if (!basename(static::$LockName)){
            die('Locker: Not a filename.');
        }

        // It doesn't help
        clearstatcache();


        if (file_exists(static::$LockName)){    // returns false always
            die('Already running');
        } else {
            $myfile = fopen(static::$LockName, "x");    // Tried with 'x' and 'w', no luck
            fwrite($myfile, 'Keep it alive');           // Tried with file_put_content also, no luck
            fclose($myfile);
        }

        // The following function returns true by the way!
        // echo file_exists(static::$LockName);

    }
    function __destruct(){
        // It outputs content
        echo file_get_contents(static::$LockName);
        unlink(static::$LockName);
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Why file_exists returns false always?

Comment: When you run the script, can you visibly see the file being created? Does the user running the script have the correct permissions? Try writing another script that uses `is_writable(__FILE__);` and check if PHP can write to the directory.

Comment: @Daniel User have the correct permission BUT I can't see the file while it's inside the loop. But by changing loop code to output the content of file, it does output but file is still not there. I think the file is locked somehow!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the PHP parser has noticed that you never use the variable `$Locker`, so it immediately destroys the object, which runs the destructor and removes the file. Try putting a reference to the object after the loop:

```
include "Locker.class.php";

Locker::$LockName = __DIR__.'/OneTime_[cron].lock';
$Locker = new Locker();

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    echo 'Z';
    $z = true;
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_start();
}

var_dump($Locker);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but no result. Even without last var_dump, object being destroyed successfully because it's output comes after loops content. like: `ZZZZ...ZZZZKeep it alive`

Answer (score 1):

If you're goal is to prevent a potentially long running job from executing multiple copies at the same time, you can take a simpler approach and just [`flock()`](http://php.net/flock) the file itself.

This would go in `cronjob.php`

```
<?php

$wb = false;
$fp = fopen(__FILE__, 'r');
if (!$fp) die("Could not open file");

$locked = flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB, $wb);

if (!$locked) die("Couldn't acquire lock!\n");

// do work here
sleep(20);

flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

To address your actual question, I found that by running your code, the reason the file is going away is because on subsequent calls, it outputs `Already running` if a job is running, and then the second script invokes the destructor and deletes the file before the initial task finishes running.

The flock method above solves this problem.  Otherwise, you'll need to ensure that only the process that actually creates the lock file is able to delete it (and take care that it never gets left around too long).